# Using Shell Script to Send Data to Running Process

Tags: c, bash, shell

I'm developing a project where I need a shell script to send data to a process running in the background. The script will ask for an integer and should send that value to a C process running in the background, that will be waiting for that value. Is it possible to send that information?

EDIT:
The process running in the background will be waiting for an integer (the key value). The script will capture the value (read $pin). So the idea is the scrip will send that value to a process that is the result of a ./program . If the program was ruined with '-f' flag he would wait for in the standard input, if not, not really sure how he was waiting for it to be received.

Comment: yes, is possible and there are a multitude of ways to so so. You need to provide more information, i.e., what is the background process waiting for? pipe input, fifo,  socket, shared memory, ...

Comment: "provide more information" How many instances of the script are allowed to run concurrently?

Comment: Yes, it's possible to communicate with a running process, but how you do it depends on how that process is *listening* for information. Simply injecting data into its memory space isn't a great idea (if the OS even permits it).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I would use [named] pipes (`man mkfifo`).

A trivial example (single number):

```
echo "123" | c_app | cat
```

Comment: For a one-off it might be simpler to use a plain file.

Answer (score 0):

If your background process expects stdin, then using a named pipe would work well:

`mkfifo pipe`

`./background < pipe`

(Script)

`echo "xxx" > pipe`